# Do I need to do a data migration every time I update source data of my core data entities?

Tags: swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I am fairly new to swift and core data. I am building an app where uses input ingredients and get recipes. For now, recipe data is loaded in from JSON and turned into instances of core data recipe entities when the user first loads in the app. The current implementation of this is to call the below function on app load and load in the recipe data based on whether the variable "recipesLoaded" is not true. However, this does not seem to be called when the app is updated, only when it is ever first opened.

```swift
    func loadRecipesIfNeeded() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        if !defaults.bool(forKey: "recipesLoaded") {
              // create instances of core data recipe entity 
              defaults.set(true, forKey: "recipesLoaded")
        }
```

However, I want the ability to add recipes to the source data without reloading every single old recipe as well. By only loading in the new entities, I hope to maintain the attributes of the old recipes (e.g. if the favourite attribute has been set to true).

Can anyone suggest a good way to go about this? I've been thinking I could create a User core data entity and track what version update they are up to (and match the app versioning to the recipe data versioning) and then only load in the missing versions. But I'm unsure if there is a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: This isn’t CoreData, using core data would solve you issues. Arrays don’t really belong in UserDefaults

Comment: You could, for starters, considering changing the type of recipesLoaded to a date or an integer for instance so you can determine if and for what version they have been loaded.

Comment: @loremipsum sorry for the confusion, within // create instances of core data... is my code for instantiating the core data entities. I just commented it out to simplify the question. I don't believe recipesLoaded is an Array given I used defaults.bool. Can you elaborate how exactly "core data will solve my issues" as I am already using it and am specifically struggling with data migrations.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson good idea! That's a good implementation plan if I go down the route of versioning. Will use that if I don't get any other ideas thank you.